# Varimax rotation in Python (Numpy/Scipy)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pca

Has anyone come across good pre-existing code for varimax rotation on Numpy arrays?

Something optimized in C or Fortran would be nice but all I come across is faint and distant requests for the same thing.

Comment: If you don't find anything useful then try "R". [Check wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varimax_rotation#Implementations). It says, there is an implementation. Maybe you could use something like: raw data -> R -> Python. Or you try to write a code by your own.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with R's `varimax()`. A bit surprised that Python does not (yet) have an equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I used [this library](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/) to do pca and it worked like a charm.  I am pretty sure that what you are looking for is there.

Moreover, if you know well R, you can always use R as a service using [Rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html).  It is easy and flexible to use.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but the closest think I've seen. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

I've looked up solutions for doing factor analysis and varimax rotatiion in python on stack-overflow so many times, that I recently made my own package, [fa-kit](https://github.com/bmcmenamin/fa_kit). You can install it as `pip install fa-kit` and go through the example notebooks to see how to use it.

Even though this is an old post, I'm throwing up this link in case there's anybody else in the future that gets here via google.